# SMBus Read Word Protocol

Tags: pic, i2c, smbus

I want to communicate with a device that is using SMBus. I use PIC18F26K83. I am inexperienced but before that I implemented I2C communication. In I2C communication, what I do in order to write to slave was:

1. After making configurations of I2C module, initialize it.
2. Set address buffer and byte count register.
3. Write data to be sent.
4. Then enter master start bit. ( I enabled repeated start bit.)

That was it. However, now when I check SMBus read word protocol it is like the picture:

[image: SMBus read word protocol]

Now as it can be seen this one is slightly different that what I did in I2C. First difference is, they enter master start bit first. Which I was not doing. So my questions are:

1. Does enabling I2C module enters master start bit by itself?
2. Do I really need to send start bit before setting up the address and command code and send another start bit again? Or can I simply set address and command code and then send a start bit?

Here is the part of the code for SMBus reading: (I could not test it so it may not work.)

```
  void SMBus_Data(){

I2C2STAT1.B2=1;// CLRBF=1, EMPTIES TRANSMIT BUFFER,i.e. TXBE=1

         //BUS FREE?            I2C1
 while (!I2C2STAT0.B7)  { }  // BUS FREE BFRE=1


 // I2C2CON0.B5=1; //MASTER START BIT
I2C2CNT=0X01;   //BYTE COUNT REGISTER

            I2C2ADB1=0x16;    //Address for smart battery
            I2C2TXB =0x0D; //Relative SOC

           //******START**********
           I2C2CON0.B5=1; //MASTER START BIT
           //I2C2CON0.B6=1;//Repeteated start enabled    (?)
           I2C2ADB1= 0x17; // Addresss + 1 = Read.
            Data_10 = I2C2RXB; // Read from the buffer


 }
```

Comment: As far as this protocol is concerned, reading works the same in I²C and SMBus. The complication comes from the need to write a byte before the actual read. How would you do the read in I²C? What library are you using? Why are you keeping the code secret?

Comment: I added the read code that I wrote. ( not tested it tho so not sure.) I do not use any library.